# Installing GMP on Windows with cygwin

Tags: c++, makefile, cygwin, autotools, gmp

I am new to C++ and I have to handle large integers, so I have to install GMP through Cygwin.

Any documentation I can find on installing this already assumes that you know what you are talking about, and I really don't.

Anyway, I got the right `.tar` or whatever, extracted it properly, and now any website I see says to run `./configure --prefix=${gmp_install}`...

What in the world is `gmp_install`? And what directory do I run `configure` from? Huh? I can run it from my little Cygwin terminal, but it just says no such file.

Next, I am supposed to type `make`. From where?

Help...

Comment: I absolutely will. I just had one more question below. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow (SO).

The source directory of GMP should probably contain the file called `configure`. This is the script which you have to execute to *"configure"* the build system in your environment. It means that during configuration [Autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) (the build system which is used to build GMP) will gather information about your environment and generate the appropriate `makefile`. Gathering information includes things like: understanding that you are on Windows, understanding that you are using Cygwin, understanding that your compiler is [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) and its version is x.y.z, and etc. All these steps are important for successful build.

You can specify a lot of different options to this `configure` script to tweak the configuration process. In your case, you specify the `prefix` option which determines the installation directory, i.e. the directory where you want the built and ready-to-use GMP distribution to reside. For example:

```
./configure --prefix=/D/Libraries/GMP
```

will configure the build system to install the GMP binaries to `D:\Libraries\GMP` directory.

Assuming that the GMP source directory (the one you extracted from `*.tar`) is located at say `D:\Users\Me\Downloads\GMP`, in order to build and install GMP you should do the following:

```
cd /D/Users/Me/Downloads/GMP
./configure --prefix=/D/Libraries/GMP
make
make install
```

**NOTE:** The `make` command will actually execute the `makefile` (which was generated by `configure` script) I've mentioned earlier. This file describes the process of building and installing GMP on your system.

**NOTE:** `${gmp_install}` is nothing, but an environment variable. For instance, you could do:

```
export gmp_install=/D/Libraries/GMP
./configure --prefix=${gmp_install}
```

this can be useful, for example, when you have to use the same path in multiple places, and don't want to type it everytime. There are other cases, when this is useful, but for that you'll have to learn more about [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), what they are for, and [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) scripting in general. However, all this goes far beyond the answer on your question.

You'll have to spend quite some time to understand all these things and how they fit together, and you'd probably have to ask more questions here on SO as understanding all that stuff for a beginner alone might be very challenging.

Comment: Thanks! Okay I think my problem is that when I unzipped .tar.gz file, there is no configure file in this directory. 

The following files were in the directory:

gmp/
gmp/include/
gmp/include/gmp.h
gmp/info/
gmp/info/dir
gmp/info/gmp.info
gmp/info/gmp.info-1
gmp/info/gmp.info-2
gmp/info/gmp.info-3
gmp/info/gmp.info-4
gmp/info/gmp.info-5
gmp/info/gmp.info-6
gmp/info/gmp.info-7
gmp/info/gmp.info-8
gmp/lib/
gmp/lib/libgmp.a
gmp/lib/libgmp.la

Comment: I downloaded the file from: http://www.cs.nyu.edu/exact/core/gmp/gmp-static-cygwin-4.1.tar.gz

Comment: This is already built binary distribution. You don't have to build anything yourself. However, there is no guarantee that it will work with seamlessly with your GCC, if this distribution was built with old version of GCC and you currently have newer one.

Comment: In case if this turns out to be true, and you'll have to build GMP yourself, just read my answer again, and you shouldn't have troubles.

Comment: I think I'll just download a package that contains the configure file, as this will be the most stable guarantee. Where do you recommend I download this from, as the one I downloaded obviously didn't have it? Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's obvious, from [gmplib.org](http://gmplib.org/), and here is the direct link to latest [GMP 5.1.1](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/gmp-5.1.1.tar.bz2).

Comment: sigh... I ran configure, and it was rolling along quite well. It finally errored and quit with the following message: checking for suitable m4... configure: error: No usable m4 in $PATH or /usr/5bin (see config.log for reasons).

Comment: Okay I successfully ran make and make install. All seemed good. I tried compiling a test CPP file that uses GMP and I got: gmp.h: No such file or directory. Do you know what I missed? Is there extra params for the gcc compiler?

Comment: Nope, you've forgotten to add `-ID:/Path/to/GMP/include` when compiling your test `*.cpp`. C'mon Dave, concentrate already and be careful.

Comment: Haha, I think you've genuinely underestimated how little I know about compilers or C++. It's honestly not a matter of concentration, I just don't even know how the compiler works so would not know what the -ID command is or how to include a library. I'll look in to it - don't mean to but you, but I'm just learning a lot still and starting from nothing. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I see. It's good that you started to play with open-source libraries and tools, as well as GCC toolchain. You've chosen the right way right from the beginning and don't turn away from it, because by going this way you'll learn a lot about how things fork from the inside. It is very steep learning curve but it's worth it. The biggest mistake beginners do, is that they download Visual Studio and program with it. As a result, these people usually have no understanding how compilation and linkage work, as well as C/C++ infrastructure in general.

Comment: They come here and cry about errors, but even after we help them, they still don't understand what was the cause, and just keep programming some crap, and cry about new errors, if you know what I mean. `:)` I wish you best of luck with learning C++ and its infrastructure. Oh, and by the way the compiler switch is not the `-ID`, but `-I`, and `D` was just a drive letter. `:)`

Comment: @AlexanderShukaev, why in Earth do you suggest to install to /D/Libraries/GMP instead of something reasonable like /usr/lib/... ? (On cygwin, I mean...) And yes, libraries go to /usr/lib but includes go to /usr/include etc, so its understandable that non-linux people get confused by such vague (and even contradictory) instructions. Also, that's not a question of C++ but of the cygwin / *nix OS infrastructure.

Comment: @Max, to begin with, the person had a chance to learn how installation directory structure of a typical Unixish library looks like, learn about `-I` and other compiler options.  Specifying `--prefix=/usr` or `--prefix=/usr/local` is a no brainer afterwards.  The question is 7 years old and I bet OP moved on already, e.g. just for the record, you can see how the person prospered in the years to come: [dthree/cash](https://github.com/dthree/cash).  You don't have to be "linux people" (whaaat?) to learn these concepts.  Would you mind telling exactly what is _vague_ and _contradictory_ here?