# Installing/ Using GMP Library

Tags: c, gmp

I'm trying to install & use the GMP library with my codeblocks IDE (using cygwin) on windows 10.

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049726/installing-gmp-on-windows-with-cygwin)

This helped a lot (I needed to run the Cygwin terminal as 'Administrator' to allow the 'make install'

I got the gmp library to install eventually but had a problem in that I couldn't specify the install location as in:

```
./configure --prefix=\C:\C_Notes\Libraries\GMP
```

When I tried I got the following error:

> configure: error: expected an absolute directory name for --prefix: :    prefix: C: C_Notes Libraries GMP

hence its installed in its default location (install check said everything is fine)

Hence couple of questions I'd like answering if possible:

1. What did I do wrong when specifying the '--prefix' - what is an absolute directory name?
2. What is the default installation of the library now?
3. Any pointers how to use the library within codeblocks?

Comment: I've reformatted your question to make it clearer. Please make a note of how I've done it so you can use these techniques next time.

Comment: Hi Richard - thank you.  Im not sure how to add the highlighting - what is needed please

Comment: The path in your error message doesn't match up to the path in your `configure` invocation. Which one is wrong?

Comment: Hi Shawn - Sorry I was a little ambiguous - I showed the example command, but the actual error.  I've updated it so the both the actual input & returned error are shown